# Dictionary comprehension set value to None

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to loop through every value in a dictionary and replace '' with None. What am I doing wrong?

```
data = {'phone': '', 'email': 'joe@hotmail.com', 'fname': 'Joe', 'zip_code': '', 'address2': '', 'address1': '', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'lname': 'Yang'}

clean = {k: v=None for k, v in data.items() if v == ''}
```

Result

```
    clean = {k: v=None for k, v in data.items() if v == ''}
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use shorthand-if as a value expression, not comprehension conditional (which will in fact remove key entirely).

```
data = {'phone': '', 'email': 'joe@hotmail.com', 'fname': 'Joe', 'zip_code': '', 'address2': '', 'address1': '', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'lname': 'Yang'}
clean = {k: None if v == '' else v for k, v in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do an *assignment* in a dictionary comprehension.

What you want is a *ternary operator* that replaces empty string values with `None` and returns others as is:

```
clean = {k: None if v == '' else v for k, v in data.items()}
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Reference:

[Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)